# Complete data not loading in dynamic list and too slow, Android, Mysql

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am using this code to populate data from web-service. everything works fine except two thing:-

1. Complete data is not loaded to list only 14 records is added to list.
2. When 14 records is loaded, My device hanged till complete data is loaded( With pics), Don't know why this is happening.

   ```
   import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

   @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
   public class HindiFragment extends Fragment {
       // XML node keys
           static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
           static final String KEY_ID = "id";
           static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
           static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
           static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
           static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
           static final String KEY_VIDEO_URL = "video";
           static final String KEY_UPLOAD_BY = "upload_by";

           ListView list;
           LazyAdapter adapter;
           JSONObject json;
           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

           public Context hindiFragment=null;
           private int catId=0;
       public HindiFragment(){}

       public HindiFragment(int position) {
           // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
           catId=position;
       }

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
               Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

           StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 



            final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
              // TextView tvLabel =  (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtLabel);
              // tvLabel.setText("Hello"); try
            hindiFragment=rootView.getContext();
            try{
                //Toast.makeText(hindiFragment,  "catid is "+catId, 
                   //     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
               json=userFunction.getAndroidVersion();
                JSONArray android_version_array = json.getJSONArray("version");
                TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.android_version);
                //getting android version
                for (int i = 0; i < android_version_array.length(); i++) {
                       // creating new HashMap
                       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject myObj = android_version_array.getJSONObject(i);
                        if(! myObj.getString("version").equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(getString(R.string.android_version)))){
                        tv.setText( Html.fromHtml(myObj.getString("text")));
                        tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                        }else
                        {
                            tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                       // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                   }



                json = userFunction.getChannelData(String.valueOf(catId),0);
                JSONArray deletedtrs_array = json.getJSONArray("cat");
               //getting data list
               for (int i = 0; i < deletedtrs_array.length(); i++) {
                   // creating new HashMap
                   HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject myObj = deletedtrs_array.getJSONObject(i);
                   // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                   map.put(KEY_ID, myObj.getString("id"));
                   map.put(KEY_TITLE, myObj.getString("title"));
                   map.put(KEY_ARTIST,myObj.getString("desc"));
                   map.put(KEY_DURATION, myObj.getString("duration"));
                   map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL,UserFunctions.siteUrl+myObj.getString("thumb"));
                   map.put(KEY_VIDEO_URL,"");
                   map.put(KEY_UPLOAD_BY,"By: "+ myObj.getString("upload_by"));

                   // adding HashList to ArrayList
                   songsList.add(map);
               }
               list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
               // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
               adapter=new LazyAdapter(this.getActivity(), songsList);     

               list.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Click event for single list row
               list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                           int position, long id) {

                       HashMap<Object, String> obj = (HashMap<Object, String>) list.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                       String name = (String) obj.keySet().toString();
                       String name1 = (String) obj.get("id").toString();

                       //Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), name1, 
                           //   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent in = new Intent(rootView.getContext(), showVideo.class);
                           in.putExtra("id",name1);
                          startActivity(in);
                   }
               }); 


               list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
                   private int currentFirstVisibleItem;
                   private int currentVisibleItemCount;
                   private int currentScrollState;
                    private  boolean flag_loading=false;
                   @Override
                   public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                           int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                          this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
                           this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
                           Log.e("firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount ",String.valueOf(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount));
                           Log.e("totalItemCount ",""+totalItemCount);
                           this.flag_loading = false;
                          // if((firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount) == totalItemCount)
                           {
                               {
                               int page=   totalItemCount+1;
                                   this.flag_loading = true;
                                  this.isScrollCompleted(page);
                               }
                           }
                   }


                   private void isScrollCompleted(int page) {
                      // if (this.currentVisibleItemCount > 0 && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
                       {
                           /*** In this way I detect if there's been a scroll which has completed ***/
                           /*** do the work for load more date! ***/
                           if(this.flag_loading){
                            loadMore(rootView,page);
                           }
                       }
                   }
               });

          return rootView;
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           return rootView;

       }

       public void loadMore(View rootView,int page){
           try{
           UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
           Log.e("page ",""+page);
           int status=0;
            json = userFunction.getChannelData(String.valueOf(catId),page);
            if(json.has("video")){
            JSONArray deletedtrs_array = json.getJSONArray("video");

           for (int i = 0; i < deletedtrs_array.length(); i++) {
               // creating new HashMap
               HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject myObj = deletedtrs_array.getJSONObject(i);
               // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
               map.put(KEY_ID, myObj.getString("uid"));
               map.put(KEY_TITLE, myObj.getString("uid"));
               map.put(KEY_ARTIST,myObj.getString("video"));
               map.put(KEY_DURATION, myObj.getString("duration"));
               map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL,myObj.getString("thumb_url"));
               map.put(KEY_VIDEO_URL, myObj.getString("url"));
               map.put(KEY_UPLOAD_BY,"By: "+ myObj.getString("upload_by"));

               // adding HashList to ArrayList
               //if(!songsList.contains(map))
               {
               songsList.add(map);
               status=1;
               }
           }
            }
           if(status==1){
           list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
           // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
          adapter=new LazyAdapter(this.getActivity(), songsList);     

          list.setAdapter(adapter);
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
           }catch(Exception e){

               e.printStackTrace();
           }

       }



   }
   ```

Here is php code to populate list

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT a.id,a.media,a.token,a.pub,left(a.title,30) as title,a.thumb,a.featured,b.name as upload_by,a.duration,left(a.description,20) as descr FROM vibe_videos a left join vibe_users b on a.user_id=b.id  WHERE category  = '$cat' and pub='1' limit 13 offset $rec") or die(mysql_error());
    // check for result 
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
   $videoArray=Array();
  $i=0; 
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {           
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          //will output all data on each loop.
        $videoArray[$i]=$data;
        $i++;
        }
            return $videoArray;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

LazyAdapter:-

```
        public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            private Activity activity;
            private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
            private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
            public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

            public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
                activity = a;
                data=d;
                inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return data.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return data.get(position); 
            }

            public String getUrl(int position) {
                return data.get(position).get("KEY_TITLE").toString(); 
            }
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View vi=convertView;
                if(convertView==null)
                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

                vi.setId(0X0000);
                TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
                TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
                TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
                ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image
                TextView uploaded_by = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.upload_by); // duration

                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song = data.get(position);

                // Setting all values in listview
                title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
                artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
                duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
                uploaded_by.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_UPLOAD_BY));
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);

                return vi;
            }
        }
```

Comment: So much code!! Aleast please remove your imports... Where is your `LazyAdapter` ?

Comment: Remove the StrictMode statements and put the internet code in an AsyncTask or thread.

Comment: I modified my code but my list is not populating, I am getting data in logs but  list is not populating. Here is my modified code:-  http://pastebin.com/DxDfAnTt